# Metadata about rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Is there any built in metadata in mysql that I could query to find out when a row was created if I haven't implemented that myself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no, not really. you'd have to put a timestamp field into the table and keep it up to date yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No** there is no such way by which you can detect that. You have to create a timestamp field which will store the value of the row created.

The reason why MYSQL does not keep a track of the timestamp of the row in the metadata is because that would **[increase the general size of the table by 4 bytes per row.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html)**

Comment: Usually you add a column of datetime type with a default value such as NOW() or CURDATE(). timestamp field values may change when you update the rows.